# C++ Losing pointer reference after scope end

Tags: c++, pointers, null-pointer

I'm getting a really weird error where after I leave the `for` scope I can't access whatever my pointer was pointing during the loop even if the array holding the objects is declared in the class header.

This is the basic of the code:

`Class CTile{ /*Code*/ };`

```
Class CMap  
{  
    public:  
        CTile** tiles;  
        CMap();  
}

CMap::CMap()  
{  
    int lines = 10;
    int cols = 10;
    tiles = new CTile*[lines];  
    for(int i = 0 ; i (lower than) lines;++)  
    {  
        this->tiles[i] = new CTile[cols];  
    }  
    for(int curLine = 0; curLine (lower than) lines ; curLine++)  
        for(int curCol = 0; curCol (lower than) cols; curCol++)  
        {
            CTile me = this->tiles[curLine][curCol];
            me.setType(1);
            //do whatever I need, and inside the loop everything works.  
        }  
    int a = this->tiles[2][2].getType(); // a gets a really weird number 
    this->tiles[2][2].setType(10); // crashes the program

}
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you never seem to be initializing the columns in the tiles double array. (This is from your first for loop) You create the new CTile[cols] but never create an object inside of those.

Comment: Off topic, but you realize that `this->` is completely redundant?

Comment: @Mark: I personally like it, makes the classes own attributes / functions stand-out in the methods.

Comment: @Luke B: you realize that a `std::vector< std::vector<Tile> >` would make much of this code completely trivial of course, and only use those pointers because you like debugging nightmare and reinventing the wheel... I hope ?

Comment: @Matthieu, I've seen that reasoning used before. Personally I prefer a naming convention that makes it clear which variables are members and which are not.

Comment: @Mark: I also like a naming convention that makes it clear (for attributes) and generally uses the `_` (at work) or the `m` prefix at home. To distinguish methods from functions though, I just use `this`.

Comment: @Matthieu I just find it easier to add new values to a multidimensional array than to a vector of vector, unless there's an easier way besides declaring a new vector and pushing it back inside the first.

Comment: @Mark yes, I know `this->` is redundant, I prefer that over using prefixes on everything

Comment: @Luke B: I don't quite follow you, `CMap::CMap(): tiles(10, std::vector<CTile>(10, 1)) {}` is pretty much clearer that your three for loops. I don't even need an answer to write it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CTile me = this->tiles[curLine][curCol];
```

That should be

```
CTile& me = this->tiles[curLine][curCol];
me.setType(1);
```

Why?  Because you made a copy of CTile, instead of creating a reference to the one in the 2-dimensional array.  You might now discover that the crash has moved to the `me.setType(1)` statement.

Comment: As an aside, because you aren't using a naming convention for member variables (such as mTiles), I appreciate that you are using the explicit `this->tiles` to emphasize that `tiles` *is* a member variable.  The syntax highlighters will bring it to your eye's attention faster than your brain will remember that 'tiles' is not a local variable or parameter given to a function.

Comment: That makes sense and the code is working now, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

```
CTile  me = this->tiles[curLine][curCol];
```

Here is the problem.  `me` is a *copy*  of the original object `tiles[curLine][curCol]`, so whatever you're doing with `me` isn't reflected in the original object. The orginal object remains unchanged even if you do `me.setType(1)`. I'm sure you didn't want that.

So the fix is : use reference as :

```
CTile & me = this->tiles[curLine][curCol];
  //  ^ note this
me.setType(1);
```

Or better yet, you can simply do this:

```
tiles[curLine][curCol].setType(1); //"this" is implicit!
```